# HTML5 localStorage: Is my code following correct standards?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

OK, so I have created an HTML5 canvas game that uses localStorage. I have localStorage working perfectly but I'm not sure that it follows the correct standards, or if it is completely fine the way that I have written it.

```
//check if storage is set already, if not set the variable   
function checkLocalStorage(){  
if (localStorage.timesPlayed){  
timesPlayed = Number(localStorage.timesPlayed);  
}   
else{   
timesPlayed = 0;   
}   
}

//code snippet to increase my variable   
timesPlayed += 1;

//code snippet to set the localStorage   
localStorage.timesPlayed = timesPlayed;
```

This works perfectly!? But from what I have read, i should be using localStorage.getItem and localStorage.setItem?

Should I change the way I write localStorage??

This is just the link to the website where I learned this way to access localStorage
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/

Comment: No, i know that, but from what is already "Out there" on the web, should I be following what others have done? (referring to getItem, setItem)

Comment: This might be helpful -- good answers about setitem, getitem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, and it probably won't break, but I'd still try to cast things in the correct type when using localStorage. `getItem` and `setItem` are the preferred ways of doing things, but the thing that jumped out at me was that your methods of getting and setting the value won't work for any type but a number, which means you have to code cautiously if you're using a lot of localStorage.

You're sending a number to localStorage, where it's converted to a string. This can get you into a lot of trouble when dealing with booleans, for example:

```
var won = false;
localStorage.isWinner = won;
if (localStorage.isWinner) { // always true
  alert("You won!");
}
```

Arrays and objects get ugly too:

```
localStorage.test = {foo: "bar", dog: "cat"};
// returns "[object Object]"
```

In other words, what you have works, but it's a good habit to do things correctly and consistently from the start, as it will simplify debugging later. The correct way -- which works with strings, numbers, arrays, objects -- is this:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(value));
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key"));

// or as a de facto alternative

localStorage.key = JSON.stringify(value);
JSON.parse(localStorage.key);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really am sending a number to localStorage, then retrieving the string and using Number() to convert the string to a number so that I can increase it using timesPlayed += 1

Comment: So, I don't have to use Number() and I can still send and retrieve a string with localStorage with the way that I have set it up. But regardless, I will be switching over to getItem and setItem.

Comment: @Jacob, yeah, the way you have works. I'm not saying otherwise. But the good thing about using the `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` methods are that they will _always_ return the correct type from localStorage no matter what. If you're storing one thing in localStorage this isn't a big deal, but what happens if you come back a month later and want to refactor the code? You have to remember what you've stored as a string, what's a number, what's a boolean. It's best to just nip that problem in the bud. (I say this as someone who had this problem with an extension I made.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the array access notation for `localStorage` is part of the standard, but most browsers that implement will probably allow for that possibility. If you want to be especially careful, then use `getItem` and `setItem` - but personally, I don't foresee this being a problem.

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage) says:

> Although the values can be set and read via the standard JavaScript property access method usage of getItem and setItem methods is recommended.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#storage-0

Even the examples in that draft they use the property access notation, so I think you're OK.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I may stick with it, but I'm mostly likely going to change to getItem and setItem.

Answer (score 0):

For a small application, direct reading and writing to *localStorage* is probaby OK, however I think in a more complex application it would be a good idea to wrap *localStorage* and provide an API with get and set methods suitable for the particular application (e.g. get/setMySpecialObject and get/setMySpecialValue).

I don't think an application should care about where data is stored, it should just call an API to get or set it. The code behind the API works out how to store it and where to get it from. Genearlly it's most efficient to read and write data into an object and read/write to *localStorage* behind the scenes. Get data from *localStorage* the first time it is requested and cache it. If it's updated along the way, write back to *localStorage* as appropriate, it should not require commands from the application to do so.